# How to convert a array of string to array of float using

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a array as shown below, in that I am having a variable called `f`, I need to assign the some value for this variable `f` say 2 and convert this into a floating point array.

```
(['0.', '0.', '-6.190649155150273*^15 + 0.7747634892904517*f^2',
       '2.2098855503598858*^10 + 4.250697125128597*^-7*f^2', '0.', '0.',
       '0.', 0.0, 0.0, -1427.5184297531378], dtype=object)
```

I tried with `df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)` but it is not working

Comment: No, because those aren't numbers.  Those are formulas.  Is that really supposed to mean -6 to the 15th power?  Why isn't that just a constant?

Comment: What's the source of those strings?  Those '*^' look wrong.  `sympy.sympify` can't handle it

Comment: I am importing a list of list from wolfram mathematica, when import it into the python it become lise this

Comment: In `mathematica` those are symbolic expressions.  `sympy` is closest python package.

Comment: you're gonna need to **parse** that.

Answer (score 0):

So I presume that the math expressions for

`-6.190649155150273*^15 + 0.7747634892904517*f^2` is [image: math]

`2.2098855503598858*^10 + 4.250697125128597*^-7*f^2` is [image: math]

And, maybe my presume is wrong, but I understand that you wanna make a math expression written in the string that could run as code.

So, I will recommend `SymPy`, here is the [official website](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html), you can check the detail, I'll give you a little example.

[image]

### Explain

1. `eval`

> Python eval() to dynamically evaluate expressions from a string-based or compiled-code-based input.

2. `subs`

- dict args as function input, for your example, `{f:2}`
- be careful, here `f` is not a string, but the `symbols` variable

---

And also, if I misunderstand the math expressing meaning, you need to replace or `regexp` by yourself.